# Problema con la recepción de un archivo multipart, conversión a File y posterior subida por FTP

Tags: java, archivo, spring-boot, multipart, ftpclient

Estoy trabajando en un programa Java con Spring que recibe un archivo MultipartFile. A continuación crea un File a partir del multipart y finalmente crea un thread que se encarga de subir el archivo "File" por ftp.

El problema actualmente es que tengo que hacer esta conversión de MultipartFile a File dentro del Controller, puesto que al parecer Java/Spring no se lleva bien con los MultipartFile fuera de una clase anotada como RestController. Por esta razón, la llamada queda en espera hasta que se termina dicha conversión y se crea el hilo, momento en el que finalmente devuelvo la respuesta y comienza la subida del archivo.

¿Cómo podría hacer para devolver la respuesta al principio de este proceso, en lugar de tener que esperar a la conversión del archivo?

**Este es el controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ftp")
public class FtpController {
    

    @Autowired private FtpAction ftpAction;
    @Autowired private Environment env;

    
    @PostMapping("/upload") public Map<String, Object> uploadFile(
            @RequestParam(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile multipartFile,
            @RequestParam(name = "path", required = false, defaultValue = "/") String path
            ) throws Exception{
        
        ftpAction.validateThreads();
                
        File file = this.multipartToFile(multipartFile, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        
        Map<String, Object> response = ftpAction.uploadFile(file, path, env);
        
        return response;
    }

    public File multipartToFile(MultipartFile multipart, String fileName) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        
        String tempFolder = env.getProperty("spring.servlet.multipart.location");

        File convFile = new File(tempFolder + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            
            multipart.transferTo(convFile);
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("multipartToFile Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return convFile;
    }
}
```

**Este es el Action:**

```
@Service
public class FtpAction {
    
    static int numThreadActive;
    static List<ProcessFileAction> uploads = new ArrayList<>();
    
            
    public Map<String, Object> uploadFile(File file, String path, Environment env) throws InterruptedException, ActionException{
        
        //Compruebo que no se haya alcanzado el máximo número de subidas
        validateThreads();

        // Creo un nuevo hilo (ProcessFileAction es quien implementa el método Runnable)
        ProcessFileAction processFileAction = new ProcessFileAction (file, path);
        uploads.add(processFileAction);

        Thread thread = new Thread(processFileAction);
        thread.start();
        
        validateThreads();
        
        //RESPUESTA
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        
        response.put("fileName", file.getName());
        response.put("path", path);
        response.put("fileSize", file.length());
        response.put("activeThreads", numThreadActive);
        
        return response;
    }
    
    
    
    public synchronized void validateThreads() throws ActionException {
        
        numThreadActive = 0;
        
        for (ProcessFileAction processFileAction : uploads) {

            if (processFileAction.getIsActive()) {
                numThreadActive++;
            }
        }
        
        
        if (numThreadActive > GlobalVariables.MAX_THREADS) {

            throw new ActionException(
                            "Se ha alcanzado el máximo de " 
                            + GlobalVariables.MAX_THREADS 
                            + " subidas simultáneas.", 400); 
        }   
    }       
}
```